# Setting Variables Does Not Work on Page Load, but Does Through Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I must be missing something. My script is as follows:

```
var slideshowUL = jQuery('div.slideshow').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    imgs = slideshowUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width,
    imgsLen = imgs.length,
    current = 0;

    console.log(slideshowUL);
    console.log(imgs);
    console.log(imgWidth);
    console.log(imgsLen);
    console.log(current);
```

The output is:

```
[ul, prevObject: p.fn.p.init[1], context: document, selector: "div.slideshow.children(ul)", constructor: function, init: function…]
[img, img, img, img, prevObject: p.fn.p.init[1], context: document, selector: "div.slideshow.children(ul) img", constructor: function, init: function…]
0
4
0
```

It is not getting the width of the image. When I paste the above code DIRECTLY into the console, it returns the correct value (750).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width of zero means you are reading the value before the images have loaded. Call it on window onload and not ready/inline.

Comment: `$(window).load( function() { ... } );`

Answer (score 0):

the image is not load yet. you must ask for the width when the image is loaded.